# Docker Compose MySql and Python not working

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, docker, mysql-python

I am running MySQL on docker compose and I am connecting to MySQL workbench works fine seems like when I connect from python says connection refused.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:8.0.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./my.conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf"
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
```

Here is my python code

```
import mysql
from mysql.connector import connect
# specify database configurations
config = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 3306,
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'password',
    'database': 'mydb'
}
connect(**config)
```

```
Error :InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Comment: You are exposing your MySQL container to your localhost on port `3308` (indicated by `"3308:3306"`, where the pair there is [`HOST:CONTAINER`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)) when your Python code tries to connect on the port `3306`

Comment: also recommend not using such an early development version of [MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/). So many bug have been fix in the 3 years since this developement release.

Answer (score 0):

ALl I had to do is basically change the port to 3308 which solves my issue